# В каких случаях надо использовать range вместо xrange

Tags: python, python-2.x

В `python 3.x` используюется `xrange` вместо range.
В `python 2.x` мы можем использовать и `xrange` и `range`. `range`, как известно возращает сразу целый список, а `xrange` генератор, тем самым экономя память. А в каких случаях лучше использовать `range`?

Comment: Сам спросил и сам ответил, наверное в тех случаях, когда надо получить сразу целый список ? :)

Comment: Да, про готовый список понятно, а вот кроме целого списка?